# Do commercial spyware products allow the attacker to access services protected by PIN secured passkeys on Android/iOS phones?

Tags: spyware

There are commercial spyware products on the market that allow access to significant functions on the infected phones without the users knowledge.  These include [ALIEN and PREDATOR](https://blog.talosintelligence.com/mercenary-intellexa-predator/) from Intellexa, and [FORCEDENTRY](https://citizenlab.ca/2021/09/forcedentry-nso-group-imessage-zero-click-exploit-captured-in-the-wild/) and [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(spyware)) from NSO.

[Passkeys](https://developers.google.com/identity/passkeys) can be generated on Android and iOS.  As well as biometric identification methods this also supports PIN secured passkey generation.  If an infected device uses PIN secured passkeys to authenticate with a service can the attacker access this service?

Comment: It depends on what has been infected. Passkeys is not a standalone app but is an API involving chain of services.